# How to check if a Dictionary CONTAINS the same items as another dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have two different dictionaries, the one is kind of like a "filter", and the other one is a list of dictionaries.

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
if all(item in tutor.items() for item in filters.items()):
```

The problem with this is, that I have a list of programs, that the tutor is capable of teaching in. It could be Maple, and or Geogebra. There are a lot of different options. The problem is, that a tutor may teach in multiple programs. So if I in the filters specify the program, Maple. I don't want it to show me the tutors that ONLY teach in Maple, but all the tutors where the program is/is not a part of the programs list.

So I somehow need to rewrite `if all(item in tutor.items() for item in filters.items()):`
To something like `if contains(item in tutor.items() for item in filters.items()):`
But that of course doesn't work.

tutor dictionary would look something like this:

```
{   'age': 34,
'age_interval': '27+',
'car': 'No',
'course': '',
'educational_institution': 'Not set by tutor',
'email': 'ronaldreagon.rr@gmail.com',
'first_name': 'Ronald',
'fluent_danish': 'Not set by tutor',
'fluent_other': [''],
'gender': 'Not set by tutor',
'grade': '',
'gym_type': 'STX',
'has_second': False,
'hour_interval': None,
'hours': 0,
'id': 112306,
'inactive_reason': 'Jeg t▒r sgu ikke give ham forl▒b, s▒ g▒r ham inaktiv '
                   '-Elmar',
'last_name': 'Reagon Ravi Kumar',
'lat': 55.78319639999999,
'lat_alternative': 0,
'lng': 12.5151532,
'lng_alternative': 0,
'mobile_phone': '+45 50213154',
'more_courses': 'Yes',
'programs': 'Not set by tutor',
'status': 'Inactive',
'still_gym': 'Not set by tutor',
'subjects': 'None, ',
'tutor_address': 'Elektrovej 330 K5 2800 kongens lyngby',
'tutor_amount_of_students': 0,
'tutor_gym': 'Not set by tutor',
'tutor_qualification': 'Not set by tutor',
'tutor_uni': 'G▒r ikke p▒ en videreg▒ende uddannelse'}
{   'age': 19,
    'age_interval': '18 til 20',
    'car': 'No',
    'course': '',
    'educational_institution': 'Not set by tutor',
    'email': 'Katrinenm02@gmail.com',
    'first_name': 'Katrine',
    'fluent_danish': 'Not set by tutor',
    'fluent_other': [''],
    'gender': 'Not set by tutor',
    'grade': '',
    'gym_type': 'STX',
    'has_second': False,
    'hour_interval': None,
    'hours': 0,
    'id': 112356,
    'inactive_reason': 'Inaktiv fordi hun er Kathrine',
    'last_name': 'Mikha',
    'lat': 55.653212,
    'lat_alternative': 0,
    'lng': 12.296957,
    'lng_alternative': 0,
    'mobile_phone': '53200337',
    'more_courses': 'Yes',
    'programs': 'Not set by tutor',
    'status': 'Inactive',
    'still_gym': 'Not set by tutor',
    'subjects': 'None, ',
    'tutor_address': 'Taastrup Have 8 st. TH',
    'tutor_amount_of_students': 0,
    'tutor_gym': 'Not set by tutor',
    'tutor_qualification': 'Not set by tutor',
    'tutor_uni': 'G▒r ikke p▒ en videreg▒ende uddannelse'}
{   'age': 19,
```

And the filters, would just specify the same keys, and a value. For instance

```
{
"gym_type" "STX"
}
```

This is done through a GET request, to our API

```
@api.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def validate_api_request():
    try:
        filters = request.json
        return get_matching_tutors(filters)
    except:
        return error_response(400, "Bad request: error in body")

def get_matching_tutors(filters):
    matching_tutors = []

    for tutor in tutor_list:
        if all(item in tutor.items() for item in filters.items()):
            matching_tutors.append(tutor)
    return jsonify(matching_tutors)
```

Let's say I specify this in the API call.

```
{
    "programs": [
        "Excel"
    ]
}
```

What I would get back, is a list of all the tutors that meet the requirement of being able to teach in Excel. But a lot of the tutors may be able to teach in Excel, and another program. But I will only get the tutors that ONLY teach in Excel. So the expected result should be something like this:

```
    {
        "age": 24,
        "age_interval": "24 til 26",
        "car": "Yes",
        "course": "4. prioritet (Foretrækker fysisk)",
        "educational_institution": "Københavns Universitet",
        "email": "hdl543@alumni.ku.dk",
        "first_name": "Ahmed",
        "fluent_danish": "Yes",
        "fluent_other": [
            "Engelsk"
        ],
        "gender": "Mand",
        "grade": "7 til 8",
        "gym_type": "STX",
        "has_second": true,
        "hour_interval": null,
        "hours": 0,
        "id": 134781,
        "inactive_reason": "Blank",
        "last_name": "Osman Mohammed",
        "lat": 55.70321,
        "lat_alternative": 55.68784609999999,
        "lng": 12.530245,
        "lng_alternative": 12.5696519,
        "mobile_phone": "42313324",
        "more_courses": "Yes",
        "programs": [
            "TI-Nspire",
            "Geogebra",
            "Wordmat",
            "Excel",
            "STATA"
        ],
        "status": "Active",
        "still_gym": "Jeg er færdig med gymnasiet",
        "subjects": "Matematik B, Matematik C, Matematik Folkeskole, ",
        "tutor_address": "Frederikssundsvej 54B, 2. th.",
        "tutor_amount_of_students": 0,
        "tutor_gym": "Frederiksberg Gymnasium",
        "tutor_qualification": "Not set by tutor",
        "tutor_uni": "Økonomi"
    },
```

As you can see, I only specified Excel but I got a tutor that can teach in Excel, and other programs. So I'm thinking that I need to see if it "contains" the specified program in the API call

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of `tutor` and `filters`.

Comment: I added samples of the tutor, and filters

Comment: Are you sure `tutors` is a dict and not a list of dict?

Comment: Yes it is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry but what you expect is not clear for me.

Comment: You're talking about Maple and Geogebra, but the data you supplied does not contain either

Comment: @Corralien Since some of the data are lists, or strings seperated by a comma to indicate a list. I want to check if key and values in filters CONTAINS the value in the tutor list. So that if a person has specified more than 1 program, it would still show up

Comment: @Jasmijn the data may or may not contain, it. It will contain it if the tutor has specified that they are qualified to teach in these languages. And I will also only check if the tutor is qualified to teach in them, if I choose to do so.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what behaviour you want, so the best way is to specify the exact expected behaviour, and show us both the data and the code that you'd expect to give this behaviour. Now we only have the code, because the plain text requirements and the data are both too vague and not even connected to each other.

Comment: @Jasmijn I updated the question, perhaps it's more clear now?

Comment: @Sonny, yes that is better.

Comment: Why do you mix string and list: `'Not set by tutor'` and `['Geogebra', 'Excel']`. You should use an empty list instead of string to be easier.

Comment: @Corralien Yeah I just noticed that, I'll update the code when I got time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the long term, you'll probably want to use a SQL database with a table for the tutors and a table with the different programs with a many-to-many relationship between them.

For now, we can create some helper functions. It's not strictly necessary, but it will make the code easier to read and maintain.

```
def matches_filter(filter_value, tutor_value):
    if isinstance(tutor_value, list):
        # We want to treat this as a set of values to match
        # instead of checking for equality
        # Note: if you have to do this often, consider using sets instead of lists to store these values.
        return set(filter_value).issubset(set(tutor_value))
    return filter_value == tutor_value

def matches_all_filters(filter_dict, tutor):
    return all(filter_key in tutor and matches_filter(filter_value, tutor[filter_key])
               for filter_key, filter_value in filter_dict.items())

def get_matching_tutors(filters):
    matching_tutors = [tutor for tutor in tutor_list
                       if matches_all_filters(filters, tutor]

    return jsonify(matching_tutors)
```

Comment: Can you explain how the matches_all_filters function works? 

It works as expected, but I'd just like to get some clarity :)

Comment: So for each filter it checks if the `tutor` dictionary has the corresponding key (to prevent a potential `KeyError` when doing `tutor[filter_key]`) and if so, if `matches_filter` returns `True` if given the corresponding value of the filter and the value `tutor[filter_key]`. Is that clear? If not, please tell me what you would like me to elaborate on.